# How do I change my phpmyadmin password?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to change the password used to log in to phpmyadmin.

Seems like a simple request, but I have been googling for a while now and there are no results.

Every time it returns results of how to change password of a user in phpmyadmin not the actual phpmyadmin login itself.

I have complete access to phpmyadmin, and the SSH of the server.

I just want to change my password that logs into phpmyadmin for security reasons.

Comment: It depends. Sometimes phpmyadmin is protected directory level by an .htaccess authentication. If it's the case you have to change your .htpasswd. Besides that what you have is your actual user/password for accessing mysql.

Comment: Fixed it by changing root mysql password, thanks

Comment: @Novaly Be careful - it is probably not a good idea to use root as your mysql username unless it is for an isolated intranet. Any attacker worth his salt would certainly try that first.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the SSH access. Try using setting the root password.

Refer This [link for setting root mysql password.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html)